# Cannot open websocket connection on Vaadin's Embedded frame

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, vaadin

I am loading an embedded page inside the main page using Vaadin's UI Embedded class with type TYPE_BROWSER. Inside that embedded page I am trying to open a websocket connection on javascript, but connection cannot be established. Browser console says:

> onclose: **Event Code: 1006 Reason:**

```
com.vaadin.ui.Embedded frame = new com.vaadin.ui.Embedded(null, new ExternalResource(url));
frame.setType(Embedded.TYPE_BROWSER);
mainContent.addComponent(certificateSign);
```

If I open that frame in a new tab by **"Right Click on Frame -> This Frame -> Open Frame In New Tab"**, the connection is built successfully.

I am using Vaadin version 6.8.

I wonder if there is any restriction on Vaadin Embedded page for websocket connections?

**EDIT
Does not work on Mozilla Firefox, but works on Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Vaadin doesn't apply any restrictions for iframe or its content. To me it sounds like a FF restriction as it works on Chrome.